# How to create a page that isn't accessible via menus?

Tags: customization

I need to create a page in my site that I am able to access via url, but that won't be included in any of the navigation menus which are generated using `wp_list_pages()` on my site.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Define menus?.. It can be pages widget, wp_list_pages function output, custom menu or something custom altogether.

Comment: Ahh. Good clarifying question. I have edited my answer. I mean using wp_list_pages()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### There is a good plugin that adds a meta check box under all pages that indicates whether you want the page to show up in menus.

#### [Exclude Pages Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exclude-pages/)

The other option is to convert from wp_list_pages to the new custom menus.  When using custom menus only pages you add to the menu will be included.

Answer (score 4):

You're in luck, there's a filter. See [this line](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.1/wp-includes/post-template.php#L775) inside `wp_list_pages()`:

```
$r['exclude'] = implode( ',', apply_filters('wp_list_pages_excludes', $exclude_array) );
```

So, just hook into `wp_list_pages_excludes`:

```
// add some new page ids to the exclude list
function my_banned_pages( $exclude_array ) {
    return array_merge( $exclude_array, array( 12, 45 ) ); 
}
add_filter( 'wp_list_pages_excludes', 'my_banned_pages' );
```

Comment: Works like a friggen charm! You rock!

Comment: I changed my accepted answer to the actual answer I ended up using. Your answer is "correct" though.

Comment: @jessegavin No sweat, glad you found a solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

just pass a flag to the wp_list_pages function call. All you need to do is get the page ID you want to exclude. See the example on the codex page listed below.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages#Exclude_Pages_from_List